# My img element won't overlap its parent's parent div?

Tags: css, html, positioning

My website is set up like this:

```
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="contentainer">
         <img src="img/car.png" alt="car.png" syle="position: absolute; top:10px; left:-35px; ">
         <div id="contentLeftTop"> ... </div>
         <div id="contentRightTop"> ... </div>
         <div id="contentLeftBottom"> ... </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS that's tied to the involved elements:

```
#container {
  position:relative;
  margin:auto;
  width:820px;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:-1;
}
#contentainer {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:800px;
  background-color:#FFF;
  border:10px groove #999;
  border-radius:15px;
  z-index:1;
}
```

What seems to be happening is the image gets cut-off due to width constraints of the parent "container" div, but it successfully overlaps the "contentainer" div. What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to stick the `car.png` to the front of the page.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Where's your doctype declaration? Always add this first to prevent common issues..

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` I just omitted it thinking it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the width constraints, it's `overflow:hidden;` in the style for `#container`. By definition, this means that anything that would extend outside of `#container` gets cut off.